# Randomly changing background of JButtons in array?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently attempting to create a Battleship game. The part I'm having trouble with is when I select the "Randomize" button, I would like it to put the ships at a random part of the grid.

For example, the Carrier ship would cover 5 JButtons within the array. How do I randomly select 5 JButtons within the array that are next to each other?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.util.Random;

public class View
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JButton grid1[][];
    private JButton randomize;
    private String[] alphabet = { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };
    private String[] numbers = { "", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

    public View()
    {
        configureFrame();
        configurePanels();
        configureComponents();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void configureFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(900, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    private void configurePanels()
    {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 11));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
    }

    private void configureComponents()
    {
        grid1 = new JButton[11][11];
        for(int i = 0; i < grid1.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid1[i].length; j++)
            {
                grid1[i][j] = new JButton();
                panel1.add(grid1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length && i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            grid1[0][i].setText(alphabet[i]);
            grid1[i][0].setText(numbers[i]);
            grid1[0][i].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 19));
            grid1[i][0].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 19));
            grid1[0][i].setEnabled(false);
            grid1[i][0].setEnabled(false);
            grid1[0][i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            grid1[i][0].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        grid1[0][0].setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        randomize = new JButton("Randomize");
        randomize.setLocation(50, 65);
        randomize.setSize(100, 50);
        randomize.setFocusPainted(false);
        randomize.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                /*
                        Want to randomly put the carrier on the grid somewhere
                grid1[2][3].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                grid1[3][3].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                grid1[4][3].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                grid1[5][3].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                grid1[6][3].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                */
            }
        });
        panel2.add(randomize);
    }
}
```

I'm very new to Java, so I apologize in advance if I'm not making any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I randomly select 5 JButtons within the array that are next to each other?

1. You generate the 1st coord
2. Randomly decide if it's going to be vertically or horizontally placed
3. Then add +4 (current and 4 extra cells) in that direction.
4. Repeat this process if any of those 5 new cells to be placed on already contain a ship.